# Decomposition of N-representable density into determinantal wavefunction

Tags: wavefunction, density, density-functional-theory

My textbook "Density Functional Theory of Atoms and  Molecules" by Parr and Yang says that any N-representable density is derivable from a single determinantal wavefunction.
A density $\rho$ is N-representable if it satisfies
$$
\rho(\mathbf x) = \int |\psi(\mathbf x, \mathbf x_2, ... \mathbf x_N)|^2 d^3\mathbf x_2 ... d^3\mathbf x_N
$$
where $\psi(\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2, ... \mathbf x_N)$ is antisymmetric in exchanging any pair of its arguments. An antisymmetric wavefunction is in general a linear combination of Slater determinants. What I want to prove is that the above $\rho$ can also be written as
$$
\rho(\mathbf x) = \sum_{i=1}^N |\phi_i(\mathbf x)|^2
$$
for some set of wavefunctions $\{\phi_i\}$. But I don't know where to go beyond this point.

Can someone help me to prove this statement?

Comment: Hint: if $\psi$ is a Slater determinant then it is also anti-symmetric. Then you can derive your expression from the definition of the density operator (in terms of the Dirac delta function) through straightforward application of anti-symmetry.

Comment: Actually I am interested in the case when $\psi$ in the first equation is not of Slater determinant type.

Comment: 3 years is long for no answer, can you copy and paste into https://materials.stackexchange.com please?

Comment: @user1271772  done!

Comment: Excellent. I upvoted it. I do wonder if you've tried @lemon's idea though? You replied saying that $\psi$ is not a Slater determinant, but surely it is still anti-symmetric right? Otherwise it would seem it's not valid for fermions, and it seems you are studying electronic structure here. I do have to ask lemon though, what do you mean? I searched "definition of density operator in terms of dirac delta function" and found nothing. The only definition I know of the density operator is $\sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i |$ or the same but with an integral instead of a sum.